# Ejecutar archivos SQL usando comandos en node

Tags: nodejs, base-de-datos, postgresql

En un proyecto donde trabajo actualmente, se está usando la librería **pg-node** para usar `postgresql` de una manera fácil que permita enviando los datos y un `query` en texto plano hacer todo el tema de transacciones con la base de datos. Pero ahora se busca que los archivos que existen para:

- Crear la base de datos
- Alimentar la base de datos con un archivo seed
- Eliminar tablas
- Entre otras cosas más

Se pueda usando comandos como cuando se inicia un servidor, o se ejecutan los test, como:

- npm run serve
- npm run test

Se puedan ejecutar dichos ficheros `SQL` de forma automática.

Comment: Me extraña que tú, un usuario tan conocido del [chat] y con la reputación que tienes, hayas formulado esta pregunta tan confusa e inadecuada. Esto lo podrías haber preguntado en el chat, habemos muchos usuarios con conocimiento de NodeJS allí.

Comment: Confusa?, Sería bueno que me corrijas, y por otro lado, no preguntó mucho en el chat para no llenar todo de código y demás, una pregunta directa, y si alguien sabe pues la responderá

Comment: A ver, sin entrar mucho en detalles, un archivo SQL no es código binario ejecutable, es un archivo de texto plano con sentencias SQL como contenido. El programa `npm` te permite llamar a otros programas que reciban como argumento tu (o tus) archivos SQL. Por ejemplo, un script del `package.json` que diga: `"load_sql" : "psql -f ruta/al/archivo.sql"`. Luego puedes llamar a dicho script desde la consola con `npm run load_sql`. (asumiendo que tienes [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html) instalado en tu sistema)

Comment: Interesante eso, creo que eso es lo que busco, el martes que en el trabajo esté probando te comento si resulto para que respondas como tal, y sea una respuesta aprobada.